# How do I use the session in WebView in my other stuff (Android)?

Tags: java, android, api, rest, webview

The user **must login** through the WebView. Of course, the session is for that WebView.
But, what if I need to make REST API calls during my Android application?

Those REST API calls need the session to be authenticated , otherwise those will not work.  Is there any way I can attach the cookies of WebView into everything I do in Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But, what if I need to make REST API
>   calls during my Android application?

It is possible you can use `CookieManager.getInstance()` to get access to the cookie in your `WebView`, then add it to the `HttpClient` `CookieStore`. So long as you keep using that same instance of the `HttpClient` object, it will continue to use that same `CookieStore` and will use the cookie. However, if that cookie changes via `WebView`, you will need to go get it again. I have not tried this and do not know what problems you may encounter.